# What Algorithm can i use to find any valid result depending on variable integer inputs

Tags: c#, algorithm, matrix

In my project i face a scenario where i have a function with numerous inputs. At a certain point i am provided with an result and i need to find one combination of inputs that generates  that result.

Here is some pseudocode that illustrates the problem:

> Double y = f(x_0,..., x_n)

I am provided with y and i need to find any combination that fits the input.

I tried several things on paper that could generate something, but my each parameter has a range of 6.5 x 10^9 possible values - so i would like to get an optimal execution time.

Can someone name an algorithm or a topic that will be useful for me so i can read up on how other people solved simmilar problems.

I was thinking along the lines of creating a vector from the inputs and judjing how good that vektor fits the problem. This sounds awful lot like an NN, but there is no training phase available.

Edit:
Thank you all for the feedback. The comments sum up the Problems i have and i will try something along the lines of hill climbing.

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to find the possible inputs that yields the desired output? Without knowing what the function is - it is impossible to know, even if you can sample your function infinite number of times. However, if there is some knowledge on `f` - it might be done (for example: Is it a polynom?)

Comment: One view of what you are trying to do is to solve an *inverse problem*.  Another view is that you are trying to select a vector of `x` values to minimise the difference between a computed `y` and the target `y`, which makes yours an *optimisation problem*.  There are very many algorithms for tackling such problems, but without a lot more input about your problem there will be no good advice forthcoming.

Comment: You seem to be asking for an equation solver. It depends very much on the kind of `f` and the domain of `x_i` which method to choose. For example, if the domain of `y` and `x_i` are real numbers and `f` is an polynomial (over real numbers), you need a polynomial root finder.

Comment: If your input arguments are, as hinted at by the question title, all integers, you could start your researches at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_optimization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general case for your problem might be impossible to solve, but for some cases there are **numerical methods** that can help you solve your problem.

For example, in 1D space, if you can find a number that is smaller then `y` and one that is higher then `y` - you can use the numerical method **[regula-falsi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_position_method)** in order to numerically find the "root" (which is `y` in your case, by simply invoking the method on`f(x) -y`).

Other numerical method to find roots is **[newton-raphson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)**

I admit, I am not familiar with how to apply these methods on multi dimensional space - but it could be a starter. I'd search the literature for these if I were you.

Note: using such a method almost always requires some knowledge on the function.

Another possible solution is to take `g(X) = |f(X) - y)|`, and use some **heuristical algorithms** in order to find a minimal value of `g`. The problem with heuristical methods is they will get you "close enough" - but seldom will get you exactly to the target (unless the function is [convex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function))

Some optimizations algorithms are: [Genethic Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm), [Hill Climbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing), [Gradient Descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent) (where you can [numerically find the gradient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation))